# How to bind two select inputs and set initial value for each of them

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, binding, controller

I have this map in the scope: `$scope.graphEventsAndFields`. The objects inside it looks like this: `{'event_name': ['field1', 'field2', ...]}` (so the key is an event name and the value is an array of fields for that event.

I want to accomplish the following: to have two select inputs, one with the events and one for the fields for that event. When I change the event type, the available fields will change accordingly. Also, I want that by default, the event input to have selected the first key in the map and the field input to have selected the first field for the event above. Below those inputs, there is gonna be a search button that must call a function with the two selected values. Until now, I have this code:

Front-end:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
        <label class="control-label col-xs-2" style="font-weight: normal;">Event: </label>
        <div class="col-xs-10">
            <select class="form-control indexDropDown ng-pristine ng-valid pulseControl ng-touched"
                    ng-options="key for (key, value) in graphEventsAndFields"
                    ng-model="selectedEventForSearch" ng-change="uiSelectIndex()">
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-xs-2" style="font-weight: normal;">Field: </label>
        <div class="col-xs-10">
            <select class="form-control indexDropDown ng-pristine ng-valid pulseControl ng-touched"
                    ng-options="field for field in selectedEventForSearch"
                    ng-model="selectedFieldForSearch" ng-change="uiSelectIndex()">
            </select>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="search(selectedEventForSearch, selectedFieldForSearch)">Search</div>
```

I saw that for a (key, value) iteration, the for loops tracks by default the values. So my code in the controller looked like this:

```
let firstKey = Object.keys($scope.graphEventsAndFields)[0];
$scope.selectedEventForSearch = $scope.graphEventsAndFields[firstKey];
```

However, this only selects a default value for the event input and the selectedEventForSearch variable will be actually the array (the key) when the search function is called. If I try with something like `"key for (key, value) in graphEventsAndFields track by key"` and I set `$scope.selectedEventForSearch = firstKey` in the controller, it does not work, no default value is selected.

What am I missing? Should I change my object format (for example to have an array of objects instead of an object with multiple keys). Can I achieve what I described with this structure? (preferably). Thanks!

Comment: What is the value of `firstKey`?? and kindly remove this line and check `ng-init="selectedFieldForSearch = selectedEventForSearch[0]"`

Comment: What do you mean by what is the value of first key? It is a string. An object just for test would be this: {"phishing": ["cluster_id","brands"],"auth":["ec_insert_date","origin_ip"]}.

Comment: I removed the line, I forgot about it, I thought it might work.

Comment: Then you got your answer :)

Comment: With or without that line, it's not working. As I mentioned, whether I track by key or value, it's not working. Also, the selectedEventForSearch  is not the key, but the array (the value).

Comment: Can't you have separate flat arrays of type and values? Just will make life simple

Comment: And how do I make the connection between the first element from the first array and the first element from the second array? Should I rely on the fact that the order will be the same? Also, it's kind of weird to do this when I create my graphEventsAndFields object. There would be a lot of messy work with indexes and stuff like this. A map it's more elegant, imo.

Comment: I receive a large array of objects like {src: {event: ..., field: ...}, dest: {event: ..., field: ... }}. In an object, the events are the same, but not the fields (and there may be multiple types of events). I just iterate in the array I receive and: 1) If the key does not exist, I create one with an empty array as a value 2) If the key exists, I insert both values of the field field in the array (making sure I do not insert duplicates).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I changed the dataset format to an array with objects like `{eventName: 'evn', fields: [..., ..., ...]}`. In front-end, the code was changed to:

```
            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
                    <label class="control-label col-xs-2" style="font-weight: normal;">Event: </label>
                    <div class="col-xs-10">
                        <select class="form-control indexDropDown ng-pristine ng-valid pulseControl ng-touched"
                                ng-options="obj.eventName for obj in graphEventsAndFields track by obj.eventName"
                                ng-model="selectedEventForSearch" ng-change="uiSelectIndex()">
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-xs-2" style="font-weight: normal;">Field: </label>
                    <div class="col-xs-10">
                        <select class="form-control indexDropDown ng-pristine ng-valid pulseControl ng-touched"
                                ng-options="field for field in selectedEventForSearch.fields"
                                ng-model="selectedFieldForSearch" ng-change="uiSelectIndex()">
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And in the controller:

```
$scope.selectedEventForSearch = $scope.graphEventsAndFields[0];
$scope.selectedFieldForSearch = $scope.selectedEventForSearch.fields[0];
```

Now it works.